# how to upload image on html using raphael.js onclick?

Tags: jquery, image, upload, raphael

I have added an icon button on the HTML page and I have added a click event on it using raphael.js. When I click on this icon button, file browser opens from where I can select whichever image I want and open it. But I want to know how to handle the selected image and upload it on the HTML page as currently selected image is not getting uploaded and displayed on the html page .

Please have a look at the following code and please suggest me solution to solve this problem.

```
 a.add_pic.click(this.add_pic);   // here I am clicking on the add_pic icon button


    this.add_pic = function()     //  this function gets invoked once the click event is fired
   {

         upload = true;
         var input = $(document.createElement('input')); 
         input.attr("type", "file");
         input.trigger('click');


       if (this.files && this.files[0] && upload) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
          reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
          upload=false;
      }


    }



        function imageIsLoaded(e) 
      {           
          // code to upload and display image file on html page
      }
```